# Why is std::map::operator[] so counter-intuitive?

Tags: c++, stl, std, stdmap, language-design

It seems to me 'evil' (in the C++ FAQ sense of the word), for an operator which is generally used to access a data structure to suddenly be defined to insert data into a data structure.

I guess the issue is 'what would be better'? This question is answered easily for certain types of mapped value; for example, if we map keys to pointers, you might really like operator[] to return nullptr for a non-existent key, but that clearly doesn't work for other types.

It could throw an exception on non-existent key, or even default construct a temporary and return that without adding it to the map. What is the good reason for turning [] from read semantics to write semantics for this container type?

Comment: `operator[]` is used to access an element in a map by key.  How is this any different from accessing an array or vector element via `operator[]`?

Comment: This is one reason I generally prefer to avoid using operator-overloaded methods for some cases. Sometimes having methods with clear names (eg. `find`, `insert`) makes for code that is more explicit and readible. (Luckily the STL containers provide both, so you have the choice to use what's appropriate for you at the appropriate time.)

Comment: I think the point of the question is that `operator[]` will add an entry to the map if the key is not there, making it a non-const operation. That can be very surprising, and there's no analogous behavior in `vector` or `deque` or `string`.

Comment: As TokenMacGuy points out, operator[] is not necessarily a const operation on a vector or array, if we assign into the vector or array using operator[] (well operator[] itself is, but vector v[0]=x; is non-const). So the only difference is that for a map, we can end up growing the container, which doesn't happen for vector or deque or arrays.

Comment: I agree it's weird, and I haven't quite get over the fact that there is no `const`-overload because of this weird semantic yet :)

Comment: It's still very handy and I miss the behavior when coding in other languages :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The basic problem is that there is no syntactic way to reliably distinguish:

```
dosomething(collection[foo]);
```

from

```
collection[foo] = something;
```

in the operator's definition.  Because it may appear in either location, the class makes sure that it can handle both, providing a default to overwrite, if necessary.   If you find this to be unconscionable, then you need to avoid `std::map::operator[]` altogether.

Another reason for this is there must be some defined behavior for when the key is not in the list.  Since `operator[]` must return a value (either LValue or RValue), then it cannot return a null pointer, past-the-end iterator, or any other sentinel value.  The only remaining option would be to raise an exception.  The STL doesn't raise very many exceptions, because it is intended to be used even in cases where exceptions are not.  Some other behavior must be chosen, and this is the result.

The best way around this is to use a member function of `std::map` that doesn't have this behavior.  That would be `map::find()`, which returns `map::end` if the key is not found.

Comment: Indeed I had not considered the case where we use the operator to assign into the collection. Doh.

Comment: "you need to avoid std::map::operator[] altogether." - or use it only for keys that you have already inserted. After all, it's undefined behavior to use an out-of-range index in `vector::operator[]`, and people live with that. It would be valid (if very peculiar) for a `vector` implementation to resize the vector big enough :-) Admittedly the standard prevents implementations doing what they can do for `vector`, which is to have out-of-bounds `operator[]` blow up in debug builds.

Comment: Well, the cases *can* be distinguished by `operator[]` returning a proxy, as with `std::vector<bool>::operator[]`. It's not at the syntactic level but I don't see why it would need to be. So, that's not the reason. I guess that it simply felt more natural to be able to simply assign in new elements. It is after all an associative array, whose main job is to associate (keys and values), and so that main usage should be easily expressed. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: As it turns out (at least in my experience with the container) the automatic inserting is actually pretty useful behavior.  for instance, it's quite normal to build a map first, and then only later iterate through it.  returning a proxy would incur a performance penalty, and wouldn't actually be of any benefit in the common case.  This is doubly so in the situation that a key is *not* found.  There is no opportunity to check for a past-the-end iterator with `operator[]`, since it returns an LValue.  Use `find()` if you need to do something else.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: FWIW (not much), little proxy objects like that can typically be removed by the optimiser, and while it may be awkward (and sometimes impossible) to find a good sentinel value they might return for not-found conditions, they could still throw.  Still, I'm not seriously suggesting it's worthwhile, though I suspect a lot of beginners make mistakes with `[]`....

Comment: @Tony: I wouldn't object to even the STL containing a container just like how you describe, so long as `map` stays the way it is.  In the C++ philosophy, *a little* extra cost is a little too much, since you should never have to pay for something you don't use.  I personally like exceptions and wouldn't mind a container that returns proxies or throws all the time, but when I don't need that, I refuse to let my code suffer the slow-down.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: I agree with you there... :-).  Thinking about it a bit harder, I think this particular proxy object would require non-trivial extra cost too... my "typically removed by optimiser" claim probably doesn't apply.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: I must admit I fell in love with `boost::optional` and I think the STL design would have been much different had such a facility existed back then. Getting a null value for free gives you the opportunity not to use exceptions in many situations where you would resort to them to avoid awkward syntax.

Comment: @Matthieu: maybe types are a good example of a cost that need not always be paid.  I'm not really sure what the right way of not using them would be when the expected case is to use them.  Maybe provide a template specialization on the maybe type that doesn't throw, with the default being to throw?

Comment: You wouldn't be specializing the return type,  You'd just have the value type be either `Type` in the default or `boost::optional<Type>` in the specialized version.

Answer (score 2):

"What is the good reason for turning [] from read semantics to write semantics for this container type?"

Having thought about it for a bit longer I can think of two reasons. The first reason is efficiency. It helps to reflect on actual algorithms and whether the semantics make life easier or harder. One algorithms where the current semantics shine is in accumulating values associated with keys.

```
void f(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, double> > const& v)
{
        std::map<std::string, double> count;

        for (size_t i = 0, sz = v.size(); i < sz; ++i) {
                count[v[i].first] += v[i].second;
        }
}
```

The map semantics are nice in this case because you can rely on each value in count being initialised with zero which is likely to be what you want. In this case we only do one search into the map for each key and value pair.

If you compare that with Python (which throws an exception if the key is absent as you suggest), you get messier and less efficient code that looks like:

```
def f(vec):
        count = {}
        for (k, v) in vec:
                if count.has_key(k):
                        count[k] += v
                else:
                        count[k] = v
```

Or a slightly neater version using get() and default values.

```
def g(vec):
        count = {}
        for (k, v) in vec:
                count[k] = count.get(k, 0) + v
        return count
```

Note that in both these version two searches into the dictionary are performed for each key and value pair. Which can be a severe penalty depending on your requirements. So the C++ map semantics are necessary for efficient code in this case.

C++ has const which is a wonderful facility for protecting things from changing. I sometimes suspect that const is massively under-appreciated. In your case using const will protect you from changing the contents of your map using operator[].

The second good reason for this behaviour is that it is the same as the behaviour of associative arrays in a number of languages. Languages like Awk and Perl have had the same behaviour for associative arrays for decades. If you are coming from these languages, the behaviour of std::map is probably very intuitive.

Comment: `from collections import Counter`

Comment: But the 'single lookup' functionality could have been provided in a function call other than operator[], thus allowing efficiency without being counter-intuitive.

Comment: I have expanded the above because it struck me that if you are coming from languages like Awk and Perl this behaviour is quite intuitive. If you have a different background, perhaps map operator[] will never seem intuitive.

Comment: @Matthieu M., you know what is amusing? That class has the same semantics as std::map. "Counter objects have a dictionary interface except that they return a zero count for missing items instead of raising a KeyError."

Comment: actually, for the exact interface of the `std::map` you want `collections.defaultdict`, `Counter` is a specialization of `defaultdict` (functionally speaking).

Answer (score 1):

As TokenMacGuy mentioned, the usage of the ::operator[] can be ambiguous, and what you described was their way of handling the ambiguity.

An important thing to look at as a software developer is that 3rd party libraries are almost never written *exactly* the way you would use them. Even worse, poorly designed 3rd party libraries can damage the quality of your code.

Everything you just described can be easily accomplished by abstracting the std::map class away, and if the side effects of ::operator[] bother you that much, I would encourage that you abstract it away.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Can you elaborate on how this relates to `std::map::operator[]`?

Comment: Mostly that I am trying to get him to realize that 3rd party libraries are never a *perfect* fit. To answer, "what would be better?," the answer is, "Exactly what fits the needs your particular application. Abstract it and make it work as you need it to."

Answer (score 0):

To understand most design decisions about the STL, one needs to look at its evolution, and notably at the [SGI STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/).

A `map` is a model of an [Pair Associative Container](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/PairAssociativeContainer.html) and of a [Unique Sorted Associative Container](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/UniqueSortedAssociativeContainer.html).

The second concept is important because it is shared with `set`, for which an access by key (using `operator[]`) just does not makes sense.

The semantics of `insert` (which does not replace the value) were designed to fit both `map` and `set` (making it possible to factorize their implementation). Note that for a `set`, whose elements are immutable, replacement does not makes sense either.

It is my belief therefore, than when introducing `operator[]`, this weird semantic was chosen so that you would have an alternative to `insert` for `map` and `multimap`, instead of the slightly more complicated:

```
map.insert(std::make_pair(key, Value())).first->second = value;
```

Honestly, I would have a preferred it to behave more like `find` (with a `std::key_error`). This semantic certainly isn't intuitive.